# Git: How to list all branches that were created from a specific branch?

Tags: git

I need to generate a report with all branch names that were created from  `develop` branch (which was branched off `master` sometime in the past). My approach was to get the first and last commits in `develop` using `git log --pretty=format:"%h" master..develop`, then use the range of commits with `git branch --contains <hash>`.

However, the above approach has a few problems:

1. I need to run to commands to know the range of commits to consider in my query.
2. I'll have to repeat the `git branch --contains` command each hash in the range.
3. The output from `git branch --contains` commands will contain redundant results for most cases because of the fact that most commits are common between branches.

I'm hoping there is a better and more direct way of doing this. Below I'll try to illustrate the case of interest:

```
  master
    ^
    |                      develop
a---b                        ^
     \                       |
      --c--d---e---f---g--h--i
           \      \    \      \
            k-l    m    n      o--p
              ^    ^    ^         ^
              |    |    |         |
         branch_1  | branch_3     |
                 branch_2       branch_4

// Desired output:
branch_1
branch_2
branch_3
branch_4
```

Comment: Note that branch `develop` contains commits `a` and `b` as well. I have to guess, based on your diagram, that you mean that `develop` identifies commit `i`, and therefore contains `i` and all of its ancestors (all the way to `a`).

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I thought `git log --pretty=format:"%h" master..develop` would give me commits starting at `c`. Maybe I miss understood this command.

Comment: Yes, `master..develop` means *all commits reachable from `develop`, minus all commits reachable from `master`.* I'm just saying I would draw this differently.

Comment: why can't you just run `git branch --contains c`? All of branch_1 to branch_4 contain this.

Comment: If it's a routine task, I'd suggest you keep a record of creation of branches, by the `post-update` hook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A branch name simply points to one commit.  All *earlier* commits that are part of that branch are found by walking backwards through the graph from that point.  That's how the `master..develop` part works, for instance: it selects commits that are ancestors of `develop`, excluding any commits that are ancestors of `master`.

(Note that in, e.g., this situation:

```
          o--o   <-- master
         /
...--o--o
         \
          *--*--*   <-- develop
```

the two-dot `master..develop` syntax includes the three starred commits.)

I think what you are asking for here is:

```
for each branch name $branch:
    if $branch identifies a commit that is a descendant of any
               of the commits in the set `master..develop`:
        print $branch
```

But any commit that's a descendant of, say, commit `i` is by definition a descendant of commit `c`.  So, as [tkruse notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370057/git-how-to-list-all-branches-that-were-created-from-a-specific-branch#comment99343638_56370057):

```
git branch --contains <hash-of-c>
```

should suffice.  To find the commit to use here, you can run `git rev-list --topo-order master..develop | tail -1`.  (If you use `--reverse` and `head -1` you can get a broken-pipe failure, so the `tail -1` method is better.  Annoyingly, you cannot combine `--reverse` with `-n 1`.)

You may be worried about a glitch with this sort of case:

```
          o--o   <-- master
         /
...--o--o--1--o--o   <-- branch-X
         \  \
          2--*--*   <-- develop
           \
            o   <-- branch-Y
```

You may want `branch-X` and `branch-Y` included, and they are not going to be found by using one single `git branch --contains` operation as they're descendants of two *different* commits in the `master..develop` range, denoted here as `1` and `2`.  Here, you really do need multiple `git branch --contains`-es, or, alternatively:

```
set -- $(git rev-list master..develop)
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads | while read ref; do
    branch=${ref#refs/heads/}
    tip=$(git rev-parse $ref)
    take=false
    for i do
        if git merge-base --is-ancestor $i $tip; then
            take=true
            break
        fi
    done
    $take && echo $branch
done
```

(untested and at least one bug fixed so far).  But this will be much slower than the simple `git branch --contains` test.  The logic here is to determine whether any of the commit hash IDs in the rev-list output is an ancestor of the tip of the branch in question.

(Note that this will print `develop`—`git merge-base --is-ancestor` considers a commit to be its own ancestor—so you might want to explicitly skip that one.)

(You can speed this up a lot by finding *just* the appropriate base commits.  In the example above, for instance, there are just two.  You can then use `--contains` on those and union the named branches.  The number of bases to use is a function of the number and structure of any merge commits in `master..develop`.  It may be possible to use `git rev-list --boundary` to find *just* the boundary commits; I have not experimented with this.)

#### Addendum

I realized during lunch that there's an easy way to find the minimal set of commits for `--contains` or `--is-ancestor` testing.  Start with the complete list of commits in the range, sorted into topological order with parents first, e.g.:

```
set -- $(git rev-list --reverse --topo-order master..develop)
```

Then start with an empty list of "commits that we must inspect":

```
hashes=
```

Now, for each hash ID in the list of all possible hashes, test each one, e.g.:

```
if ! is_descendant $i $hashes; then
    hashes="$hashes $i"
fi
```

where `is_descendant` is:

```
# return true (i.e., 0) if $1 is a descendant of any of
# $2, $3, ..., $n
is_descendant() {
    local i c=$1
    shift
    for i do
        # $i \ancestor $c => $c \descendant $i
        git merge-base --is-ancestor $i $commit_to_test && return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```

After the loop is done, `$hashes` contains the minimal set of commits that can be used for `--contains` or `--is-ancestor` testing.

Comment: I'm not sure if `$i` and `$tip` are always valid commits. Because I'm getting a lot of `fatal: --is-ancestor takes exactly two commits` errors.

Comment: The output of `git rev-list` and `git rev-parse` is a valid commit (or set of valid commits), although `git rev-list` can add decorators (e.g., `--boundary` or `--left-right`). Use `-x` to observe the script in operation.

Comment: Oh, `git for-each-ref` prints three items, will fix.

Answer (score 6):

You can get awfully close with one command:

```
git log --ancestry-path  --branches --not $(git merge-base --all master develop) \
        --pretty=%D  --simplify-by-decoration --decorate-refs=refs/heads
```

That's "show me just the branch decorations in all branch-tip histories that trace back to the current merge base of master and develop".

You can get it prettier by piping the result through anything like `awk '{print $NF}' RS=', |\n'`.

Note that this (like @torek's answer) assumes you're doing this in a repo administered for archival-level stability like your production master, there's no necessary relation between branch names and commits at all, let alone a permanent, or global or unique one.   If you're trying to permanently tie commits to some external administrative record, do it in the commit message, not the branch name.

Edit: if you want a quick overview of the current branch structure since the master-develop split,

```
git log --graph --decorate-refs=refs/heads --oneline \
         --branches --simplify-by-decoration \
         --ancestry-path --boundary --not `git merge-base master develop`
```

Comment: Ah, I like this one.